# Specific Website gives PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR or equivalent in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox, safari, error-correction

I am trying to access a site that is only accessible through my work VPN. I've tried Firefox and Chrome in both normal and incognito/personal modes and receive *connection_reset* error. In Safari, I receive a statement that Safari can't open the page because the server is not responding.

I have confirmed that others are able to access the website and log into the server without problems, so I think the problem is on my end. The hack 'thisisunsafe' has no impact. So far, I have:

1. cleared cache and cookies on all three browsers,
2. confirmed that there are no proxies active,
3. confirmed that the error is not due to an extension by a) turning off extensions in mozilla, and b) trying to connect via a private window in both mozilla and chrome,
4. confirmed that I cannot ping the servers IP - I get a request_timeout.
5. I also turned off my router's firewall and tested without it - same error.
6. uninstalled and reinstalled my VPN,
7. flushed the dns cache and renewed the dhcp lease on my computer, and
8. rebooted my router and modem.

The website has (I believe) a self-signed ssl cert, and I get this in Dev Tools when I try to open the webpage.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPKqV.png)

However, given that 'thisisunsafe' doesn't work and that I can't ping the server, I'm not sure that this is the problem. At this point, I'm out of ideas. Can anyone point me in a new direction?

Comment: So have you installed the certificate in the certificate store for the user and/or machine?  Just because the certificate wasn't signed by a valid CA does not mean it's not safe to trust. Can't seem to find my answer on the subject on how to determine what the keyword is. Make sure you are typing "thisisunsafe" while viewing the page, Chrome window should have focus, for it to work

Comment: [This](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/components/security_interstitials/core/browser/resources/interstitial_large.js#19) contains/contained the current passphrase. However, you really should figure out, the reason you cannot even ping the host. Talk to your IT Administrator about that one.